# Hallar hoja de un arbol

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Necesito saber como en un árbol puedo realizar la búsqueda de la hoja del árbol más profunda. Si existieran dos hojas con la misma profundidad no importaría en cual de ellas estuviera.

Se supone que ya tengo la clase Arbol creada, y además la función que me crea un árbol a partir de una lista. Tal función la pongo en el siguiente código. También pondré la función que me permite saber si un nodo es hoja o no.

```
def profundidad (arbol):
    profundidad = 0
    izdo = 0
    dcho = 0

    if Es_hoja(arbol):
        profundidad = 1
        info = arbol.info
        return profundidad , info
    else:
        if not arbol.izdo.esvacio:
            izdo,infoi = profundidad(arbol.izdo)
        elif not arbol.dcho.esvacio:
            dcho,infod = profundidad(arbol.dcho) 

        if (izdo > dcho):
            return izdo+1,infoi
        else: 
            return dcho+1, infod
```

Con este código intento obtener la profundidad del árbol y la información que posee, sin embargo me da error.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de código que inicialice un árbol como el que hay que pasarle, para hacer pruebas? Ah! Y el código de `Es_hoja()`.

Comment: Ya he realizado el cambio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores importantes en la función `profundidad()`.

- El primero es que inicializas una variable con el mismo nombre que la función, `profundidad=0`, por lo que cuando más adelante intentas llamar recursivamente a esa misma función con `profundidad(arbol.izdo)`, por ejemplo, va a fallar pues en ese momento el identificador `profundidad` ya no es la función, sino el entero.

  Realmente no necesitabas para nada el entero `profundidad`, por lo que podemos eliminarlo como verás en la implementación que propongo después.
- El segundo error es lógico. El `eilf not arbol.dcho.esvacio:` debería ser simplemente `if not arbol.dcho.esvacio:`. Piensa que tienes que examinar ambas ramas, tanto la izquierda como la derecha. Tal como lo tienes, si la izquierda no era vacía, entonces ya no examinarías la derecha.

Mi propuesta sería entonces:

```
def profundidad (arbol):
    izdo = 0
    dcho = 0

    if Es_hoja(arbol):
        info = arbol.info
        return 1 , info
    else:
        if not arbol.izdo.esvacio:
            izdo,infoi = profundidad(arbol.izdo)
        if not arbol.dcho.esvacio:
            dcho,infod = profundidad(arbol.dcho) 

        if (izdo > dcho):
            return izdo+1,infoi
        else:
            return dcho+1, infod
```

### Mejoras adidionales

Tu función `Es_hoja()` es un poco redundante. Podría dejarse así:

```
def Es_hoja(arbol):
  return  arbol.izdo.esvacio and arbol.dcho.esvacio
```

El programa puede ser más fácil de depurar si los árboles incluyeran un método `__repr__()` apropiado, que devuelva una representación del árbol como cadena. Propongo la siguiente:

```
class Arbol:
   # Resto de métodos como estaban...
   # ...

  def __repr__(self):
    if self.esvacio:
      return ""
    elif Es_hoja(self):
      return "{}".format(self.info)
    else:
      return "{} -> ({}, {})".format(self.info, self.izdo, self.dcho)
```

Esto te permitirá hacer un `print(arbol)`, por ejemplo:

```
f = Arbol("f")
e = Arbol("e", f)
d = Arbol("d")
c = Arbol("c", d, e)
b = Arbol("b")
a = Arbol("a", b, c)
print(a)
```

---

```
a -> (b, c -> (d, e -> (f, )))
```

Que es otra forma de decir que el árbol tiene esta estructura:

```
     a
   /   \
  b     c
       /  \
      d    e
          /
         f
```

Por cierto que `print(profundidad(a))` produce en este caso el resultado `(4, 'f')`, que es correcto.